# How to extract content disposition in pyshark

Tags: python, wireshark, pyshark

In layer http packet has content disposition but I cannot get this with pyshark in python

I use `packet.http.content_disposition` but it not display

```
import pyshark

def capture_live_packet(network_interface):
    capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface=network_interface, display_filter='http')
    for packet in capture.sniff_continuously():
        print(packet.http.content_disposition)
```